Which is better: tensorflow 2.3.0 with GPU or tensorflow 2.18.0 with only CPU?
What is the speed of running tensorflow 2.3.0 with GPU relative to tensorflow 2.18.0 with only CPU?
Hardware

Laptop: MacBook Pro 15-inch 2012 64-bit.
OS: Windows 10 Pro 22H2
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4850HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz
GPU: GeForce GT 750M, compute capacity 3.0, GeForce Game Ready Driver 425.31 WHQL.

Purpose

Learning keras in R.

Why tensorflow 2.3.0?

Because my laptop's internal GPU has a compute capacity 3.0 whereas most current tensorflow applications require a compute capacity 3.5+, I had to compile my own tensorflow installer wheel file "tensorflow-2.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl" and use compatible CUDA 10.1 and cuDNN 7.6 to take advantage of the existing GPU.
Accordingly, I need to run python version 3.7.11 (default, Jul 27 2021, 09:42:29) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], numpy 1.18.5, keras 2.11.0 (reported by pip list | grep keras, but keras:::keras_version() reports 2.4.0), TensorFlow v2.3.0 but not later versions.
The tensorflow session detects 1 CPU and 1 GPU, as listed in the hardware

What about tensorflow 2.18.0?

I can update to python 3.12.7, keras 3.6, and tensorflow 2.18 as of 11/15/2024.
But I will lose access to GPU because latest versions of software are not compatible with older GPUs.

I wonder whether I should choose tensorflow 2.3.0 with GPU or tensorflow 2.18.0 with only CPU, given my limitations of hardware capacity and software versions. I understand that some keras functions (e.g. layer_random_rotation() for image rotation and data enhancement requires Tensorflow version >=2.6) are only available in later tensorflow versions, but I have not started computer vision applications or huge data sizes (in multiple GB) yet. Does the GPU access provide enough benefits to justify skipping latest software versions?
